# p:schedule eventSelect is null

Tags: jsf, events, primefaces, schedule

My Ajax event "eventSelect" is not working. When I click on an event on my calendar, it's display the dialog box but it's empty. When I run my application in debug mode, the parameter selectEvent is null whereas for ajax event "dateSelect" ,this one works fine(even when the dialog box appears, it displays the date).

appointment.xhtml

```
 <h:form>
  <p:schedule id="schedule"
            value="#{Appointment.eventModel}"
            widgetVar="myschedule"
            timeZone="GMT+2">

    <p:ajax event="dateSelect"
            listener="#{Appointment.onDateSelect}"
            update="eventDetails"
            oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />

    <p:ajax event="eventSelect"
            listener="#{Appointment.onEventSelect}"
            update="eventDetails"
            oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
</p:schedule>

<p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog"
          header="Appointment Details"
          showEffect="clip"
          hideEffect="clip">

    <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel for="title" value="Titles:" />
        <p:inputText id="title"
                     value="#{Appointment.event.title}"
                     required="true" />

        <p:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
        <p:calendar id="from"
                    value="#{Appointment.event.startDate}"
                    timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />

        <p:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
        <p:calendar id="to"
                    value="#{Appointment.event.endDate}"
                    timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />


        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save"
                         actionListener="#{Appointment.addEvent}"
                         oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();
                                     PF('eventDialog').hide();"/>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Appointment.java

```
public class Appointment implements AppointmentInterface {

    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
        return eventModel;
    }

    public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
    }

    public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
    }

    public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        if (event.getId() == null) {
            eventModel.addEvent(event);
        } else {
            eventModel.updateEvent(event);
        }

        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC Any idea why the event is null??

Comment: If you debug, you can also set a breakpoint in the getEventModel and step trough your code  and see what happens there.

Comment: @Kukeltje ok You mean when I click on the event it  will enter the getEventModel method also??

Comment: Yep…  most likely. All behind the scenes…

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes it enters the method and creates an instance of event model.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The problem is about creating the eventModel :

```
public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
        return eventModel;
}
```

This code will be invoked several times when creating the view, and it will be creating a new empty instance of eventModel each time. You should check if eventModel is null before creating a new instance

```
public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
      if (eventModel==null) {
          eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
      }
      return eventModel;
}
```

So the instance of eventModel will only be created once and schedule will use this instance.

Comment: Or do it in a @PostConstruct annotated method